# Truncate a fractional value to particular number of bits?

Tags: numerics, output-formatting, precision-and-accuracy, number-bases

If I have a fractional value, how can I truncate (not round) that to a certain number of bits, like 8?

For example, for Pi 3.141569265359... the fractional part is 0.141569265359...

```
NumberForm[BaseForm[FractionalPart[N[Pi]],2],8]

0.00100100001111110110101010001
```

But this is giving me 8 decimal digits of PI in base 2. What I want is 8 binary digits in base 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumberForm is for representation purposes only. I suggest you use [`RealDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RealDigits.html), and then take the number of bits you need from its first returned element or, better yet

```
Rest[ First[ RealDigits[FractionalPart[N[Pi]], 2, 8+1]]]
```

EDIT: corrected to give only the bits needed.